# Modifying generalized input so there is no default input

Tags: inputfield, user-interface, demonstrations

I'm currently working on a demonstration and attempting to utilize the `Interpretation` command based on the example provided in the "Generalized Input" tutorial [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/GeneralizedInput.html).

Regarding the particular example of plotting a function over a specified interval:

```
Interpretation[
    {f = Sin[x], min = 0, max = 2 Pi},
    Panel[
        Grid[
            {{Style["Plot", Bold], SpanFromLeft},
             {"Function:", InputField[Dynamic[f]]},
             {"Min:", InputField[Dynamic[min]]},
             {"Max:", InputField[Dynamic[max]]}}
             ]
     ],
    Plot[f, {x, min, max}]
 ]
```

Evaluating this cell sets the sine function as the default plot, but I would like to have the reader put their own in. I've tried setting `f=Invisible[1]` with the hopes of having anything entered multiplied by an unseen 1, but entering anything becomes invisible. I've also tried using `Spacer[1]` which works as far as what I want to have, but evaluating the cell generates a template with awkward placement of the `"Function:"` label. This is fixed once a function is entered.

Is there a way I can make the input boxes blank from the start? Or at least a prettier use of `Spacer`?

**Edit:** Another problem with using `Spacer` here is that plugging in negative numbers for the plot range make it say things like `-4+`, which prevents an actual plot from being made.

**Edit:** After some sifting through the documentation, I came across a similar example:

```
Panel[
    DynamicModule[
        {f = Sin[x]}, 
        Column[{InputField[Dynamic[f]], Dynamic[Plot[f, {x, -5, 5}]]}]
        ]
]
```

Would it be any easier to adapt the blank-input idea to this code?

Comment: I think I finally worked out a useful answer to your original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really don't have any experience with `Interpretation`, but it seems that   requesting a function name or pure function rather than a function form, and initializing `f` to `Null` gives the behavior you ask for.

```
Interpretation[{f = Null, min = 0, max = 2 Pi}, 
  Panel[
    Grid[{
      {Style["Plot", Bold], SpanFromLeft}, 
      {"Function:", InputField[Dynamic[f], FieldHint -> "Enter a function"]}, 
      {"Min:", InputField[Dynamic[min]]}, 
      {"Max:", InputField[Dynamic[max]]}}]],
  Plot[f[x], {x, min, max}]]
```

Initial appearance:

[image: initial]

With a function name:

[image: cos-panl]

[image: cos]

With a pure function:

[image: pure-pnl]

[image: pure]

I don't like the idea of requesting a function form (e.g., `Sin[x]` rather than `Sin`) because it couples the demonstration a particular symbol `x` for the independent variable. I think it would be possible to rewrite this to parse the variable out, but how to do that would be different question.

Comment: Four letters was all it took! This is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks! I also like the `FieldHint` addition. As for your comment regarding the functions - I've tweaked my demo so that it only plots linear functions, so I'm making it ask for slope and intercept.